# How to make ffmpeg remux an iPhone MOV (HEVC) that works on Apple products?

Tags: iphone, video, ffmpeg

I want to remux a HEVC file (without encoding). I have tried most options, even removing audio, but I cannot get an output file that plays smoothly with Apple products.

First I AirDrop any MOV from an iPhone recorded with the camera in HEVC.

Then run:

```sh
ffmpeg -i IMG_4605.MOV -c copy out.mov
```

Then if I send `out.mov` back to the iPhone and try to play it back, it plays back with glitches while seeking, like this: (original to the right)

[image: Result]
[image: Original]

When I try to drag the file into a new iMovie project and try to play it back, it freezes the whole iMovie app and needs a force quit.

Doing the same with the original causes no issues, so obviously there is something wrong with the way ffmpeg remuxes it, or something wrong with Apple's software.

```
ffmpeg -i IMG_4605.MOV 
ffmpeg version 4.2.2 Copyright (c) 2000-2019 the FFmpeg developers
  built with Apple clang version 11.0.0 (clang-1100.0.33.17)
  configuration: --prefix=/usr/local/Cellar/ffmpeg/4.2.2_2 --enable-shared --enable-pthreads --enable-version3 --enable-avresample --cc=clang --host-cflags= --host-ldflags= --enable-ffplay --enable-gnutls --enable-gpl --enable-libaom --enable-libbluray --enable-libmp3lame --enable-libopus --enable-librubberband --enable-libsnappy --enable-libtesseract --enable-libtheora --enable-libvidstab --enable-libvorbis --enable-libvpx --enable-libwebp --enable-libx264 --enable-libx265 --enable-libxvid --enable-lzma --enable-libfontconfig --enable-libfreetype --enable-frei0r --enable-libass --enable-libopencore-amrnb --enable-libopencore-amrwb --enable-libopenjpeg --enable-librtmp --enable-libspeex --enable-libsoxr --enable-videotoolbox --disable-libjack --disable-indev=jack
  libavutil      56. 31.100 / 56. 31.100
  libavcodec     58. 54.100 / 58. 54.100
  libavformat    58. 29.100 / 58. 29.100
  libavdevice    58.  8.100 / 58.  8.100
  libavfilter     7. 57.100 /  7. 57.100
  libavresample   4.  0.  0 /  4.  0.  0
  libswscale      5.  5.100 /  5.  5.100
  libswresample   3.  5.100 /  3.  5.100
  libpostproc    55.  5.100 / 55.  5.100
Input #0, mov,mp4,m4a,3gp,3g2,mj2, from 'IMG_4605.MOV':
  Metadata:
    major_brand     : qt  
    minor_version   : 0
    compatible_brands: qt  
    creation_time   : 2019-12-29T10:20:56.000000Z
    com.apple.quicktime.location.ISO6709: +01.3602+103.9897+024.438/
    com.apple.quicktime.make: Apple
    com.apple.quicktime.model: iPhone 11
    com.apple.quicktime.software: 13.3
    com.apple.quicktime.creationdate: 2019-12-29T18:20:56+0800
  Duration: 00:00:09.00, start: 0.000000, bitrate: 24882 kb/s
    Stream #0:0(und): Video: hevc (Main) (hvc1 / 0x31637668), yuv420p(tv, bt709), 3840x2160, 24659 kb/s, 29.99 fps, 29.97 tbr, 600 tbn, 600 tbc (default)
    Metadata:
      rotate          : 90
      creation_time   : 2019-12-29T10:20:56.000000Z
      handler_name    : Core Media Video
      encoder         : HEVC
    Side data:
      displaymatrix: rotation of -90.00 degrees
    Stream #0:1(und): Audio: aac (LC) (mp4a / 0x6134706D), 44100 Hz, stereo, fltp, 192 kb/s (default)
    Metadata:
      creation_time   : 2019-12-29T10:20:56.000000Z
      handler_name    : Core Media Audio
    Stream #0:2(und): Data: none (mebx / 0x7862656D), 0 kb/s (default)
    Metadata:
      creation_time   : 2019-12-29T10:20:56.000000Z
      handler_name    : Core Media Metadata
    Stream #0:3(und): Data: none (mebx / 0x7862656D), 0 kb/s (default)
    Metadata:
      creation_time   : 2019-12-29T10:20:56.000000Z
      handler_name    : Core Media Metadata
    Stream #0:4(und): Data: none (mebx / 0x7862656D), 17 kb/s (default)
    Metadata:
      creation_time   : 2019-12-29T10:20:56.000000Z
      handler_name    : Core Media Metadata
```

```
ffmpeg -i out.mov
ffmpeg version 4.2.2 Copyright (c) 2000-2019 the FFmpeg developers
  built with Apple clang version 11.0.0 (clang-1100.0.33.17)
  configuration: --prefix=/usr/local/Cellar/ffmpeg/4.2.2_2 --enable-shared --enable-pthreads --enable-version3 --enable-avresample --cc=clang --host-cflags= --host-ldflags= --enable-ffplay --enable-gnutls --enable-gpl --enable-libaom --enable-libbluray --enable-libmp3lame --enable-libopus --enable-librubberband --enable-libsnappy --enable-libtesseract --enable-libtheora --enable-libvidstab --enable-libvorbis --enable-libvpx --enable-libwebp --enable-libx264 --enable-libx265 --enable-libxvid --enable-lzma --enable-libfontconfig --enable-libfreetype --enable-frei0r --enable-libass --enable-libopencore-amrnb --enable-libopencore-amrwb --enable-libopenjpeg --enable-librtmp --enable-libspeex --enable-libsoxr --enable-videotoolbox --disable-libjack --disable-indev=jack
  libavutil      56. 31.100 / 56. 31.100
  libavcodec     58. 54.100 / 58. 54.100
  libavformat    58. 29.100 / 58. 29.100
  libavdevice    58.  8.100 / 58.  8.100
  libavfilter     7. 57.100 /  7. 57.100
  libavresample   4.  0.  0 /  4.  0.  0
  libswscale      5.  5.100 /  5.  5.100
  libswresample   3.  5.100 /  3.  5.100
  libpostproc    55.  5.100 / 55.  5.100
Input #0, mov,mp4,m4a,3gp,3g2,mj2, from 'out.mov':
  Metadata:
    major_brand     : qt  
    minor_version   : 512
    compatible_brands: qt  
    encoder         : Lavf58.29.100
  Duration: 00:00:09.00, start: 0.000000, bitrate: 24860 kb/s
    Stream #0:0: Video: hevc (Main) (hvc1 / 0x31637668), yuv420p(tv, bt709), 3840x2160, 24659 kb/s, 29.99 fps, 29.97 tbr, 19200 tbn, 19200 tbc (default)
    Metadata:
      rotate          : 90
      handler_name    : Core Media Video
      encoder         : HEVC
    Side data:
      displaymatrix: rotation of -90.00 degrees
    Stream #0:1: Audio: aac (LC) (mp4a / 0x6134706D), 44100 Hz, stereo, fltp, 192 kb/s (default)
    Metadata:
      handler_name    : Core Media Audio
```

If I open `out.mov` in QuickTime and do a *trim* and export it, then it it still "broken", so I'm thinking there's nothing wrong with the actual muxing into MOV, because QuickTime is passing the error on.

I noticed that `out.mov` has different parameters `19200 tbn, 19200 tbc` (vs original `600 tbn, 600 tbc`). However, if I force set these to 600 with `-video_track_timescale 600` the output file is still broken.

Anyone got some insights?

Comment: Strange. Can only provide poor suggestions in this case: `ffmpeg -i IMG_4605.MOV -c copy -map 0 -movflags +faststart out.mov` Also try ffmpeg build from current git master branch (from zeranoe, evermeet, or homebrew w/ `--HEAD` option). Use [hash demuxer](https://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg-formats.html#hash) to verify checksum is same between input and output to rule out some non-ffmpeg related issue.

Comment: ...should be "hash muxer" not "hash demuxer".

Comment: Thanks for the suggestions. I already tried to copy all streams and several different movflags, as well as the git master ffmpeg version. As you suggested, I now tried to run hash on `IMG_4605.MOV` and `out.mov` and they do have the same hash. This means that it must be something broken in the format, metadata, or timestamps, right?

Comment: I did notice, however that `out.mov` has different parameters `19200 tbn, 19200 tbc` (vs original `600 tbn, 600 tbc`)

Comment: I tried to force set these to 600 with `-video_track_timescale 600` but the output file is still broken.

Answer (score 1):

Based on this article:
https://aaron.cc/ffmpeg-hevc-apple-devices/

I recommend adding `-tag:v hvc1` in your command

```
ffmpeg -i IMG_4605.MOV -c copy -tag:v hvc1 out.mov
```